# how to check if file exist and not empty in awk using wildcard in filename or path

Tags: awk

I am trying to create a small awk line that should go through several paths and in each path find a specific file that should not be empty (wildcard). If the file is not found or empty it should print "NULL".
I did some searching in stackoverflow and other places but couldn't really make it work.

Example: path is /home/test[1..5]/test.json

```
awk -F"[{}]" '{ if (system("[ ! -f FILENAME ]") == 0 && NR > 0 && NF > 0) print $2; else print "NULL"}' /home/test*/test.txt
```

If the test.txt is empty or does not exists it should print "NULL" but meanwhile when it is not empty it should print $2.

In the above example it will just skip the empty file and not write "NULL"!

Example execution /home/ has test1, test2, test3 path and each path has one test.txt (/home/test1/test.txt is empty):

The test.txt file in each of the /home/test* path will be empty or the below kind of text (always one line):
{"test":1033}

```
# awk -F"[{}]" '{ if (system("[ ! -f FILENAME ]") == 0 && NR > 0 && NF > 0) print $2; else print "NULL"}' /home/test*/test.txt
"test":1033
"test":209
```

File examples:

```
/home/test0/test.txt (not empty -> {"test":1033})
/home/test1/test.txt (empty)
/home/test2/test.txt (not empty -> {"test":209})
/home/test3/test.txt (not exist)
```

But for ../test1/test.txt I would like to see "NULL" but instead I see nothing!

I would like to have a printout like the below:

```
"test":1033
NULL
"test":209
NULL
```

What am I doing wrong?

BR

Comment: You are confusing awk and shell. awk is for manipulating text. A shell is for manipulating files and processes and sequencing calls to tools. The latter is what you are trying to do.

Comment: What should the outcome be if the file exists but is not readable? What if it doesn't have 2 fields?

Comment: i have updated my question with some more information and the outcome. Thanks again to you all!

Comment: You still didn't answer my questions:  What should the outcome be if the file exists but is not readable? What if it doesn't have 2 fields?

Comment: This case will never happen! Only those cases not exist, exist, empty, not empty. It will be always readable!

Comment: You still didn't answer the 2nd question in my comment - what if it is non-empty but only has 1 field? I just posted an answer assuming that can't happen either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you are asking correctly, there is no need for a `system` call.  One can use `ENDFILE` to check to see if a file was empty.

Try this:

```
awk -F"[{}]" '{print $2} ENDFILE{if(FNR==0)print "NULL"}' /home/test*/test.txt
```

`FNR` is the number of records in a file.  If `FNR` is zero at the end of a file, then that file had not records and we print `NULL`.

*Note:*  Since this solution use `ENDFILE`, [Ed Morton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1745001/ed-morton) points out that GNU awk (sometimes called `gawk`) is required.

#### Example

Suppose that we have these three files:

```
$ ls -1 home/test*/test.txt
home/test1/test.txt
home/test2/test.txt
home/test3/test.txt
```

All are empty except `home/test2/test.txt` which contains:

```
$ cat home/test2/test.txt
first{second}
1st{2nd}
```

Our command produces the output:

```
$ awk -F"[{}]" '{print $2} ENDFILE{if(FNR==0)print "NULL"}' home/test*/test.txt
NULL
second
2nd
NULL
```

#### Test for non-existent files

```
for d in home/test*/; do [ -f "$d/test.txt" ] || echo "Missing $d/test.txt"; done
```

Sample output:

```
$ for d in home/test*/; do [ -f "$d/test.txt" ] || echo "Missing $d/test.txt"; done
Missing home/test4//test.txt
```

Comment: That OP said `If the file is not found or empty it should print "NULL"`. That script handles just the part after the `or` (i.e. `empty`), not the part before it (i.e. `not found`). You should mention it requires GNU awk for ENDFILE and since you are using GNU awk even a file with no terminating newline won't register as NULL, it'll be handled as it if did have the terminating newline.

Comment: Even if it is only when the file exists but empty or not, it is working. I believe we can include also the case where the file is missing. Thanks again

Comment: @FotisK I'm glad it is working.  Regarding non-existent files, note that the glob `home/test*/test.txt` will, _unless none exist_, only show files that exist.  I just added to the end of the answer, code to test for non-existent files.

Comment: @EdMorton Thanks for the info.  Your knowledge of awk is encyclopedic.  Answer updated with a note on GNU and  `ENDFILE`.

Answer (score 0):

```
for dir in home/test*; do
    file="$dir/test.txt"
    if [ -s "$file" ]; then
        # exists and is non-empty
        val=$( awk -F'[{}]' '{print $2}' "$file" )

    else
        # does not exist or is empty
        val="NULL"
    fi
    printf '%s\n' "$val"
done
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!